# How can I access the source code relevant to the William Carter mysteries in the previous Don't Starve updates?

Tags: dont-starve

I'm here with interest in the William Carter puzzles put out by Klei. What I'm really after is the cool ASCII art that Klei hides in the don't starve hidden webpage source files. I found all of this out on the Don't Starve wiki. Can anyone give a straightforward walkthrough of how to access the source codes of these websites and\or provide the ASCII art that they contain?

Thanks in advance, this might be a somewhat difficult question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about accessing website source code, which isn't a gaming specific activity.

Comment: @Frank In a way you're right. But on the other hand, the viewing of the source code relates to a ARG-like treasure hunt related to the tagged game. It may not directly relate to gaming, but I see it related at least tangentially. _(Of course, my opinnion on this is rather biased in this case.)_

Comment: @Frank I would classify this as an Easter Egg.

Comment: @blaughw I would classify the ARPG as an easter egg.  I wouldn't classify how to look at source code as something we deal with.

Comment: Well I got a great answer either way 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source of websites is freely accessable by just about any browser (to a point, some of it may be processed at server side, but that's never publicly visible). The access method and the way they show it varies, but most often the way to view the source of a website is to press `Ctrl`+`U`. This shortcut works with IE and Chrome, at least.

There doesn't seem to be ASCII art at the sites outside some (mentioned at the [William Carter Puzzles -Wiki Page](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/William_Carter_Puzzles)) puzzle sites, like [Dark Enlightement](http://www.dontstarvegame.com/science/mdocs/4/dark-enlightenment.html) or [Ladies and Gentlemen](http://www.dontstarvegame.com/science/mdocs/5/ladies-and-gentlemen.html). But I didn't test this outside the basic front pages of Don't Starve.

However, you should be able to see the quite nice ASCII art at the sources of the linked two pages (and others mentioned at the Wiki page) by using the shortcut I mentioned above.